# Forcing ArrayFire to switch backends in Python

Tags: python, module, arrayfire

I have been attempting to force [ArrayFire](http://arrayfire.org) to use its CPU backend, rather than the default CUDA backend. According to [this documentation page](http://arrayfire.org/arrayfire-python/), you only need to call `arrayfire.set_backend('cpu')`. However, when I attempt to do this, an error is thrown with the message `global name 'backend' is not defined`. If you take a look at [the source code](http://arrayfire.org/arrayfire-python/_modules/arrayfire/library.html#set_backend), you will see that a global variable `backend` is defined within the module directly before the `set_backend` function is implemented. The following functions set and get various attributes of this `backend` object. My question is: is an internal implementation error on their part causing this error, or is there something I'm doing wrong (or that can be done on my part to fix this)? I haven't worked much with Python modules before, and would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: I am the maintainer of arrayfire-python, the error seems weird. Can you open an issue on the github page: https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire-python/issues. Can you also try to include the full stack trace of the error ?

Comment: I just discovered the cause. Someone else had previously been messing with the installation of arrayfire I'm using, and `backend = _clibrary()` was commented out in the source code.

Comment: Glad that is resolved :)